# passing '*' as command line argument to shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have the following shell script in bash:

```
function zzqfoo {
    python ~/my/dir/path/zzqfoo.py $(abspath $1) $2
}
```

The idea is to call the python program "zzqfoo.py" with a local filename on the command line, but zzqfoo.py receives the absolute path to the file thanks to `$(abspath $1)`.

However when I call

`>>> zzqfoo myfile *`

the shell corrupts the `*` and sends god knows what to zzqfoo.py as second argument.

How do prevent the `*` from being corrupted? (I want zzqfoo.py to receive the second command line argument as-is.)

Thanks!

Comment: What does "as-is" mean to you here? What does `zzqfoo.py` expect in its arguments?

Comment: I meant that zzqfoo receives the character '*'.... (for which the solutions below work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the shell corrupts the `*` and sends god knows what to zzqfoo.py as second argument.

It doesn't "corrupt" the `*`. It does what it always does: expands the `*` as wildcard, matching the names of files and directories in the current directory.

You should:

- quote the `*` when passing it as an argument
- quote `$1`, `$2` etc. when using it in the function, so that the shell doesn't do word splitting or wildcard expansion on them

So:

```
function zzqfoo {
    python ~/my/dir/path/zzqfoo.py "$(abspath "$1")" "$2"
}
```

And run it so:

```
zzqfoo myfile '*'
```

Comment: You are correct that quoting $1, $2 etc. will prevent word splitting (and it's a good practice anyways!) but it's not necessary for wildcard expansion, since the shell won't perform it on the expanded contents of the variables, so technically it's not needed to solve this problem, only quoting the literal asterisk with `'*'` is enough to fix this in this particular case.

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger you sure? Try `sh -c 'echo $1' _ '*'` and check.

Comment: Ah sorry my bad, indeed it will perform wildcard expansion if not quoted. (I was probably thinking of variable assignments.)

Answer (score 1):

Quote it:

```
$ zzqfoo myfile "*"
```

Or

```
$ zzqfoo myfile \*
```

Or

```
$ zzqfoo myfile '*'
```